# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()...After I right click and click on "INSPECT" on my view page I get this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner at MVC and trying to create a page. I have three tables in my database. I am using Entity Framework with a database-first approach and I created these three tables as classes in my `Models` folder. I also created a new class called `AllClasses` and defined each of this three classes in this new class.

I am trying to get 3 pictures from the `tblCharacter` tables' `CharacterImageURL` column.

When I run my code, the program is running without any error. So what is the problem?

The problem is I can not display these three photo on my view page. I will add some screenshots to show you problem more detailed.
BY THE WAY I HAVE IMAGE URL'S ON THE DATABASE NOT THE IMAGES LIKE  .jpg. What I have on my database is spmething like `images/avatar/Chewbacca-icon.png`
I KNOW THERE ARE SIMILAR QUESTIONS BUT NONE OF THE SOLUTIONS WORKED FOR ME...

This is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using StarWars.Models;

namespace StarWars.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        StarWarsFunClubDBEntities myobject = new StarWarsFunClubDBEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myclass = new All();
            myclass.Characters = myobject.tblCharacters.ToList();

            return View(myclass);
        }

        public ActionResult SWHome()
        {
            var myclass = new AllClasses();
            myclass.Avatars = myobject.tblAvatars.ToList();
            myclass.Characters = myobject.tblCharacters.ToList();
            myclass.Comments = myobject.tblComments.ToList();
            return View(myclass);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my home page `SWHome.cshtml`:

```
@model StarWars.Models.AllClasses

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>SWHome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo"> <img src="~/images/Star_Wars_Logo.png" alt="Alternate Text" /> </div>
            <div class="sitename"><h4>Star Wars Fun Club</h4></div>
        </div>
        <div class="question"><h5>What do you think about the new characters of Star Wars: The Force Awakens(2015)?</h5></div>
        <div class="photo">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Characters)
            {   
                <div class="innerphoto">
                    <img src="@item.CharacterImageURL" alt="" />
                </div>
            }

        </div>
        <div class="comment"></div>
        <div class="addcomment"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

These are my auto-generated classes:

```
namespace StarWars.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblAvatar
    {
        public int AvatarID { get; set; }
        public string AvatarName { get; set; }
        public string AvatarImageURL { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class tblComment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public string Expression { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public int AvatarID { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class tblCharacter
    {
        public int CharacterID { get; set; }
        public string CharacterName { get; set; }
        public string CharacterImageURL { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using StarWars.Models;
using StarWars.Controllers;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace StarWars.Models
{
    public class AllClasses
    {
        public IEnumerable<tblAvatar> Avatars { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblCharacter> Characters { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<tblComment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my view (`SWHome`) where I want to show the photos:

[image]

This screenshot shows the problem at the bottom:

[image: As you see,in the HTML <div class="innerphoto"> part image sources can be seen but I can't get them on my view page...So I think the problem is not with the DB connection...]

As you see, in the HTML `<div class="innerphoto">`, image sources can be seen but I can't get them to be displayed on my view page. So I think the problem is not with the DB connection.

This is my solution explorer:

[image]

I have new screeshoot for the one who interested in:
[image: The red ones are the photos which I could not be able to display on my view page...Maybe this would help for one of the guys who trt to solve the problem.]

Comment: Does your 'images' folder contain the image that you want to show? Alternatively, you can try this: <img src= "@Url.Content(Model.YourImageLocationPropertyHere)"  />

Comment: THESE WORKED ,I GOT THE IMAGES...Thank you so much... What I wrote is        
 <img src="@Url.Content(item.CharacterImageURL)" alt="" style="width:225px; height:225px;"/> instead of  <img src="@item.CharacterImageURL" alt="" style="width:225px; height:225px;"/>...

Comment: great! Do you mind accpting this if post the solution as an answer?

Comment: Please post as a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
<img src="@item.CharacterImageURL" alt="" />
```

You cannot access the image from root directory (i.e. wwwroot) directly.

Try this:

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.YourImageLocationPropertyHere)" />
```

Url.Content is used when you wish to resolve a URL for any file or resource on your site and you would pass it the relative path.

Hope this helps.